# integer data frame to date in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 10 dates which I read into R as integers. Here is the data frame:

```
19820509
19550503
20080505
19590505
19940517
19690504
20050420
20060503
19840427
19550513
```

We'll called it df.

I have attempted a few different lines of code here to simply change each value to the date format in R like this: `"1982-05-09"`

```
df <-  as.Date(df, "%Y%m%d")
```

doesn't work and neither does

```
 df <- as.POSIXlt(df, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

or

```
df <- as.POSIXct(df), format = "%Y/%m/%d", origin = "19820509")
```

I keep getting an error saying "do not know how to convert 'df' to class "date" or either of the POSIX formats.

I thought this would be more simple. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use it on the column of the data frame, not the data frame itself.

Comment: Here a POSIX solution where df is your data.frame: `as.POSIXct(as.character(df[,1]), format="%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to reference specific columns rather than just referencing the data frame. If the variable containing the integer dates is in a data frame `df` and is called `x`, you can do this:

```
df <- transform(df, x = as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d"))

#             x
#  1 1982-05-09
#  2 1955-05-03
#  3 2008-05-05
#  4 1959-05-05
#  5 1994-05-17
#  6 1969-05-04
#  7 2005-04-20
#  8 2006-05-03
#  9 1984-04-27
# 10 1955-05-13
```

This converts the integers to character strings, then interprets the strings as dates.

If you multiple columns containing dates in this format, you *can* convert them in one fell swoop, but you have to do it slightly differently:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")))
```

Or even better, as docendo discimus mentioned in a comment:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: That works! I tried that initially, but it was still being fussy. The character conversion works. Thank you.

Comment: For the lapply code, you could slightly modify it to: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d"))` so you don't need the data.frame call

Comment: @docendodiscimus: Nice! Thanks for pointing that out. Added it to the answer.

Comment: nice! Good call, @docendodiscimus

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution, it requires the `lubridate` package. You can use the `ymd` function of the `lubridate` package as a "replacement function". Just pick the column you want to convert ad replace it with the `ymd` version of it.

```
 library(lubridate)
 data[ , 1 ] <- ymd(data[, 1])
```

This package provides more functions to parse data or strings to dates, ymd (y = year, m = month, d= day) all with this simple scheme.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I've been looking into the package more for dealing with different date related tasks in R.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = c(data$DATE)
date <- as.Date(paste(v), format("%Y%m%d"))
date
```

`data$DATE` is the column carrying date in integer format like `20000131`, `20000201`