# Convert integer YYYYWW to date

Tags: r, date, integer, format

The variable I want to convert is an integer in the form of `YYYYWW`.

So, for example **200901** represents week 1 of **2009**, **201223** --> ***23*** of ***2012*** and so on.

I want to convert this variable into date format based on weeks in a year.

So in my example  **01-2009** and **23-2012** or a similar format. I already tried several lubridate and [ISOweek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) functions but never come up with a good result.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: A date always includes a day. What you have there are not dates. How you should proceed depends on the next steps you want to do.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if it works for weeks but try the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29928301/5335354

Something like:

```
df <- transform(df, x = as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%U"))
```

Comment: Answers are supposed to be "this works". This should be a comment.